# $c/a$ ratio for an ideal hexagonal close-packed (HCP) structure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, geometry, crystals

> Show that the $c/a$ ratio for an ideal hexagonal close-packed (HCP) structure is $\left(\frac{8}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{2} = 1.633$.
> [image: for c/a ratio]

I believe $a$ is the length of $a_1$ and $a_2$.
I figured that to be "ideal" we'd need the distance from any 1 point to it's nearest neighbors to be $a$.  So starting from the center of the bottom plane (and calling it the origin) the points on the bottom plane are all already a distance $a$ away.  Then I just need to worry about the 3 in the middle plane.  1 of them should have position $r=\frac23 a_1 + \frac13 a_2 +\frac12 a_3$.  Then the length of this one squared is $$\left(\frac23 a\right)^2 + \left(\frac13 a\right)^2 + \left(\frac12 c\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac23 \frac13 a^2\cdot \cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\right)=a^2$$
Note that $c$ is orthogonal to $a_1$ and $a_2$.  Evaluating this, I'm getting $\frac{c}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle between $a_1$ and $a_2$ should be $2 \pi/3$, not $\pi/3$. Your equation is then
$$\left(\frac23 a\right)^2 + \left(\frac13 a\right)^2 + \left(\frac12 c\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac23 \frac13 a^2\cdot \cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})\right)=a^2.$$
This gives $\frac49 a^2 + \frac19 a^2 + \frac14 c^2 - \frac29 a^2 = a^2$ which implies $c^2/a^2 = 8/3.$